# Trim string from specific character

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in a table which has timezones.

Example: `Australia/Brisbane`

I need to just show a portion of the string.

I need to just show `Brisbane`

So, I have created a new column in my table called 'short_name', and I want to set the value of that to 'Brisbane'.

Is there a way I can find the '/', and then copy the rest of the string into the new column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a query like that to select the value after `/`:

```
select substring(name, 
                 charindex('/', name) + 1, 
                 len(name) - charindex('/', name) + 1) 
from table1
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31d2ba/3)

So if you want to update the new column, you can use:

```
update table1
set newcolumn = substring(name, 
                 charindex('/', name) + 1, 
                 len(name) - charindex('/', name) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using insert into select and in the select statement use substring.

For example, the function SUBSTRING('212-555-1234', 9 , 4) returns:
'1234', pass the name of the column and the correct index as it follows.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(<column_name>, position, length)
FROM <table_name>
```

Then use Insert into statement as it follows.

```
INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;
```